# Ckeditor on textbox - contenteditable="true" broke redirect to another page on Firefox

Tags: ckeditor

I have an issue using CkEditor in textbox with `contentEditable = true` when I try to redirect to another page it does not work.

Can anyone guide me to solve this?

Just happen on Firefox.